# SQL to convert database column for price in text to numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I run a query to convert price column from text to numbers(BIGINT) in a database? Is it possible to do such processing using only SQL queries?

```
Price
————-
2 millions 5 hundreds thousands
52 thousands
3 hundreds 25 thousands
10 millions 30 thousands
```

**UPDATE**

Like what you guys commented, I guess this task is better done with other language instead of SQL.

Comment: This looks like a quite complicated task for a SQL database.

Comment: It might be possible to do this but it would be more trouble that it is worth. Besides, an answer that does this would be very complex and hard for someone to step in and support it down the road. You should look into storing your data differently in your database. It would be easier to manipulate this data with a language like PHP/Python/Java and insert it into your database in the form of an actual number instead of inserting your data as a string and trying to extract a number from that. Sorry if that's not the answer you are looking for, but it's the best one.

Comment: Whose smart idea was it to make price column like that?

Comment: @Eric: the instructor, I imagine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do it? Sure you can but you really shouldn't. Here's an example (abbreviated) of what it might look like:

```
 SELECT CAST(CONCAT(
      CASE WHEN priceData.millions IS NOT NULL
           THEN LPAD(priceData.millions, 3, '0')
           ELSE '000',
      CASE WHEN priceData.thousands IS NOT NULL
           THEN LPAD(priceData.thousands, 3, '0')
           ELSE '000'
     -- additional branches for hundreds, tens, whatever else you want to process
 ) as BIGINT) price
 FROM (
      SELECT 
           REPLACE(
                REGEX_SUBSTR(table.price, '[0-9]* millions'),
                ' millions',
                '') as millions,
           REPLACE(
                REGEX_SUBSTR(table.price, '[0-9]* thousands'),
                ' thousands',
                '') as thousands,
           REPLACE(
                REGEX_SUBSTR(table.price, '[0-9]* hundreds'),
                ' hundreds',
                '') as hundreds'
     -- additional branches for hundreds, tens, whatever else you want to process
      FROM table
 ) as priceData
```

This is a minimal proof of concept, but it will require a lot of building out before it works. It also makes a lot of assumptions about your data, will be insanely slow, and will make whoever comes to maintain your code want to gouge their eyes out. I mainly provided it to show you just how sad it will make you to put it all together.

The real solution would be to store the numbers as BIGINT before the data gets to the db at all. If you can't do that, I would do this kind of processing programmatically in whatever it is that's querying your db.